# Verification Code Expiration Issue: Code Expires Immediately Instead of After 1 Hour

Tags: php, html, forms

I created user verification system where a verification code is generated and sent to users for account confirmation. However, there's an issue with the expiration mechanism of the verification code. Instead of adhering to the intended expiration period of 1 hour, the code appears to expire immediately.

controllerUserData.php

```
if (isset($_POST['verification'])) {
    // Initialize an array to store the digits
    $digits = [];

    // Length of verification code
    $totalDigits = 6;

    // Loop through the digits and retrieve them
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalDigits; $i++) {
        $inputName = 'digit' . $i;
        $digit = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST[$inputName]);
        $digits[] = $digit;
    }

    // Concatenate the digits to form the verification code
    $verificationCode = implode('', $digits);

    // Check the verification code in the database using a prepared statement
    $checkCodeQuery = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE code = ?";
    $stmtCheckCode = mysqli_prepare($con, $checkCodeQuery);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtCheckCode, "s", $verificationCode);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtCheckCode);
    $codeResult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmtCheckCode);

    // Check if the verification code exists in the database
    if (mysqli_num_rows($codeResult) > 0) {
        $userData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($codeResult);
        $email = $userData['email'];
        $code = 0;
        $status = 'verified';

        // Check if the verification code is still valid (within 1 hour)
        $storedTimestamp = isset($_SESSION['verification_timestamp']) ? $_SESSION['verification_timestamp'] : 0;
        $currentTimestamp = time();
        $timeoutSeconds = 3600;

        // Calculate the expiration time
        $expirationTime = $storedTimestamp + $timeoutSeconds;

        if ($currentTimestamp <= $expirationTime) {
            // Update the code and status in the database using a prepared statement
            $updateOtpQuery = "UPDATE usertable SET code = ?, status = ? WHERE code = ?";
            $stmtUpdateOtp = mysqli_prepare($con, $updateOtpQuery);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtUpdateOtp, "iss", $code, $status, $verificationCode);
            $updateResult = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtUpdateOtp);

            // Check if the update was successful
            if ($updateResult) {
                // Set the user's email in the session and redirect to the home page
                session_start();
                session_regenerate_id(); // Regenerate session ID to prevent session fixation
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                unset($_SESSION['verification_timestamp']); // Clear the timestamp after successful verification
                header('Location: home.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                // Display an error message if the update fails
                $errors['otpError'] = "Failed while updating code!";
            }
        } else {
            // Display an error message if the verification code has expired
            $errors['otpError'] = "The verification code has expired!";
        }
    } else {
        // Display an error message if the verification code is incorrect
        $errors['otpError'] = "You've entered an inavalid code!";
    }
}
```

verification.php

```
<?php
    // Include necessary files
    require_once "controllerUserData.php";

    // Check if the user is logged in
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    if (!$email) {
        // Redirect the user to the login page
        header('Location: login.php');
        // Terminate the script to ensure a clean redirect
        exit();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <form action="" autocomplete="" method="post">
         <h1><Verification></h1>
        <div class="codeContainer">
            <?php
            $totalDigits = 6;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalDigits; $i++) {
                echo '<input class="code active" type="text" maxlength="1" name="digit' . $i . '" placeholder="" required>';
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        <button class="primary-button" name="verification" type="submit">Verify</button>
        <p class="text-error text-center" id="errorMessage"><?php echo isset($errors['otpError']) ? $errors['otpError'] : ''; ?></p>
    </form>
    <script src="src/assets/js/form/codeContainer.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to ensure that the verification code remains valid for the intended 1-hour duration instead of expiring immediately when I type in the verification code and click verify.
Any improvements to the code are much appreciated. I am a newbie.

Comment: I don't think we have all the code. Where is `$_SESSION['verification_timestamp']` set, for instance?

Comment: I used ChatGPT to create the verification timestamp. I'm somewhat of a beginner coder and am not familiar with the terms. The verification system worked before I tried using ChatGPT for a verification code time limit.

Comment: Please don't let ChatGPT write code for you that you don't understand. Stay in control of your code. You can use AI to help you program, but if you add code you don't understand it's going to be a disaster.

Comment: Do you know how I could create an expiration after 1 hour for the verification code?

Comment: try to write a simple one, if you do not know how to write it, it means that you may need more time studying the programming language itself.

Comment: Does this `throw` an error stating that `The verification code has expired!`? In my understanding, your code should ALWAYS run into the `// Update the code and status in the database using a prepared statement` code because you are setting `$currentTimestamp` then immediately checking it agains `$expirationTime` which is set to be `3600` bigger.

Comment: How would this code look like. I'm not familiar with php?